# Is there way to set variable from a stage local variable to Jenkins global variable?

Tags: jenkins, groovy, jenkins-pipeline, jenkins-groovy, jenkins-job-dsl

Is there a way to access stage local variable in jenkins global pipeline, I'm trying to use the `var1` value from `Example stage` in `post always` block.

```
// Declarative //
pipeline {
    agent any
    stages {
        stage('Example') {
            steps {
                def var1 = sh 'ssh yourname@yourmachine 'grep uploadRate= /root/yourscript' '
            }
        }
    }
    post { 
        always { 
            echo 'Reading a Var1 Value' + var1
        }
    }
}
```

error:

```
Error when executing always post condition:
groovy.lang.MissingPropertyException: No such property: var1 for class: WorkflowScript
```

Comment: every solved this issue?

Answer (score -1):

You cant directly call the variable which assigned in build steps in post action. 
As a solution what you can do is pass the 'Example' stage result to file and then by using [Environment Inject Plugin](https://plugins.jenkins.io/envinject/) you can access the value in post action.

After installed the plugin set the file name in job configurations. 
[plugin setup](https://i.stack.imgur.com/y1Kj5.png)

```
pipeline {
    agent any
    stages {
        stage('Example') {
            steps{
            script {
                sh 'date > output.txt'    
            }
          }
        }
    }
    post { 
        always { 
            script {
            curDate = readFile 'outFile.txt'
            echo "The current date is ${curDate}"    
            }
        }
    }
}
```